# Detect change in input text box made by another jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, signalr

I'm putting together a Backbone app as a POC for my company and I'd like to include real time updates. I'm using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to faciliate the update.

The app I'm creating is a calculator, so when an update occurs in a specific input box I want a number of event listeners to fire off, altering their calculations.

This works fine binding the `input` event to the text box in question. The backbone view detects the changes and the correct methods fire off.

However, when I update the text box using another jQuery method nothing happens. Once I receive a message from the SignalR server, I have the jQuery coded to take the message and set the input box's `text` and `val` properties.

So far I've tried binding the `input`, `change` and `keyup` events to the text box and I cannot get any to fire when I use the jQuery code to alter the contents of the text box.

**Backbone app**

```
var SliderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#inputElements"), 

    events: {
        "slide": "updateVal",
        "input td input#purchasePayment": "updatePurchasePay", //Text box/Event I'm working on
        "keyup td input#fixedRate": "updateFixedRate",
        "keyup td input#returnSpxUp": "updateReturnSpx"
    },

    //This method should fire anytime the value in the #purchasePayment box changes
    //This works if I'm typing in the browser, however if the values are 
    //changed via a message received from SignalR nothing happens
    updatePurchasePay: function () {
        var val = this.$el.find('td input#purchasePayment').val();
        this.model.set({ purchasePayment: val });
        console.log('Model :' + this.model.get('purchasePayment'));
    },

    updateFixedRate: function (e) {
        var val = this.$el.find('td input#fixedRate').val();
        this.model.set({ fixedRate: val });
    },

    updateReturnSpx: function (e) {
        var val = this.$el.find('td input#returnSpxUp').val();
        this.model.set({ returnSpx: val });
    },

    updateVal: function () {
        var val = this.$el.find('td div#slider').slider("option", "value");
        this.model.set({ slidervalue: val });
    }
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    //This method receives updates from SignalR
    //Anytime a character is received I place it in the 
    //appropriate text box
    chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {

        //Neither the change, input, or, naturally, keyup events
        //fire when these lines of code are executed. 
        $('#purchasePayment').val(message);
        $('#purchasePayment').text(message);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        //Telling the page to send whatever is in
        //a specific text box to the SignalR server
        //each time 'keyup' event is detected
        $('#PusherInput').on('keyup', function () {
            var input = $('#PusherInput').val();
            chat.server.send(input);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no events firing when changing value programmaticaly. AngularJS can do this by using it's watch methods.

You can slightly modify your code to this: 
View events

```
events: {
    //other event handlers
    "change td input#purchasePayment": "updatePurchasePay"
},
```

There is no way of triggering oninput event programmaticaly (but you can try by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) post), so you can trigger change event.

And your sagnalr client code:

```
chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
    $('#purchasePayment').val(message).change();
    $('#purchasePayment').text(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger javascript events with jquery

```
$("element").trigger("event");
```

Hope this will be helpfull.
Good luck.